# Any opensource tool to connect from Ubuntu machine to remote SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I tried enough searching for a tool in Ubuntu to connect to my remote SQL Server but in vain. Can someone please suggest me a tool (cross-platform) which helps me manage DB in remote SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Java/JDBC based tool should work. Those that come to my mind are:

- [Squirrel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/squirrel-sql/)
- [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) (from Oracle, not OpenSource but free)
- [SQL Developer](http://sqldeveloper.solyp.com/) (not from Oracle)
- [Execute Query](http://executequery.org/)
- [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net)

You can either use the free [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) JDBC driver, or the one [supplied by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using NetBeans as your IDE, you can use the database explorer there. All you need to do is to add the MS SQL driver that you can download from [MS download center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2505).